# Solving partial differential equation using substitution, first and second partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A PDE is given as
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$
And a suggestion for variable substitution is given as
$$u = x+y, v = x-1.$$

I do the substitution and end up with

$$2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$.

Which I am unsure about how to solve, I have only had to deal with exercises with a constant on one side.

The following is additions using the comments and my extended attempts:

We let $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = g$$ and get $$2 \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = g \Rightarrow g = e^{\frac{1}{2}u}$$
We then have
$$
2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} = e^{\frac{1}{2}u}\\
2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = v e^{\frac{1}{2}u} + C_1(u)\\
2 f = 2ve^{\frac{1}{2}u} + u C_1(u) + C_2(v)\\
f = (x-y)e^{\frac{1}{2}(x+y)} + (x+y)C_1(x+y) + C_2(x-y)
$$
Did I make any errors here? Or rather, which errors did I make?

Comment: You are trying to solve $$2f_{uv} = f_{v}$$ and so just integrate both sides with respect to $v$ first, then solve the resulting inhomogeneous ODE in $u$. Alternatively, let $f_{v} = g$.

Comment: If I integrate both sides I end up with $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} 2 = f + C_1(u)$$ which I dont know what to do with next.

Comment: @JonLachmann: Then try the other way: $g=f_v$ gives $g_u=\frac12 g$, and perhaps you know which functions that equal their own derivative (up to a factor $\frac12$)?

Comment: That would give me $g = e^{\frac{1}{2} u}$, but how do I continue from there? I think my main concern are not the individual steps, but seeing the path that I need to take towards the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your change of variables. $v=x-1$ should be $v=x-y$.

Your calculus is correct up to :
$$2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$.
Then with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = g$ 
$$2 \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = g \quad\Rightarrow\quad g = F(v)e^{\frac{1}{2}u}$$
Don't forget $F(v)$ with arbitrary function $F$.
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = F(v)e^{\frac{1}{2}u}$$
$$f=e^{\frac{1}{2}u}\int F(v)dv+G(u)$$
$$f=e^{\frac{1}{2}u}H(v)+G(u)$$
$$f(x,y)=e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}H(x-y)+G(x+y)$$
$G$ and $H$ are arbitrary functions.